# QPushButton 100% height of QGridLayout's cell

Tags: qt, height, qpushbutton, qgridlayout

```
qroupBoxButtons = new QGroupBox();  
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;  

pushButtonPlus = new QPushButton( tr( "+" ) );  
layout -> addWidget( pushButtonPlus, 1, 1 );  
/* add another elements to layout */  
layout -> setColumnStretch( 1, 25 );  
/* set column stretch to other columns */  
qroupBoxButtons -> setLayout( layout );  
/* add qroupBoxButtons to another QGroupBox's layout
```

I'm trying to set 100% height like this:

```
pushButtonPlus -> setStyleSheet( " QPushButton { height: 100%; } " );
```

or:

```
pushButtonPlus -> setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored );
```

But it doesn't work normal. Button always have 100% of width and only standart height. And when window resizes it stay in one height.

How can I set 100% height without using resize event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way how to do that:

```
pushButtonPlus->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

I don't know why `QSizePolicy::Ignored` doesn't work for this, even if it's described in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html) pretty straightforwardly.

Comment: I'm trying to set up `QSizePolicy::Expanding` only for first argument in `setSizePolicy` and it was `width`. Thanks